# Determine which thread a ThreadLocal variable is associated with in the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, thread-local

I have a class that looks a little like this:

```
public class IdHolderManager{
    private final ThreadLocal<String> idHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public String getId(){
        return idHolder.get();
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        idHolder.set(id);
    }

    public void clearId(){
        idHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

In short, I do `idHolder.setId("abcd")` in one part of a Spring app, but when I try to `.getId()` a while later, the return value is always null. I'm unfamiliar with ThreadLocal/etc, but I was thinking this might be because I was calling `.getId()` when the currently running thread is no longer the one I did `.setId("abcd")` on?

In Eclipse's debugger mode, however, hovering over `idHolder` shows this window that says "(id = x)". In both the `setId("abcd")` and `getId()` calls, idHolder has the same "(id = x)" label - does this mean that `idHolder` is associated with the same thread in both instances? If this is the case, any ideas as to how `idHolder`'s value gets cleared would be highly appreciated since I never explicitly call `clearId()` between `setId("abcd")` and `getId()`.

Comment: The fact `idHolder` shows `id = x` because it is one and the same object, however, internally a `ThreadLocal` stores a value per thread. So, if you query it from thread-1 you get a different value (or no value) than when you query it from thread-2.